# Datewise logging file using slf4j

Tags: logging, spring-boot, slf4j

I want datewise different logger file like

```
2017-05-20.log
2017-05-21.log
2017-05-22.log
2017-05-23.log
```

in my spring-boot project where logger is used slf4j not log4j.

my application.properties file setting:

```
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
logging.level.com.propatterns=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.file=logs/application.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare logback.xml file spring application.properties or yml file. This step is optional if we keep the config name as logback.xml.

   logging.file: logback.xml
2. Just create a standard **logback.xml** in the root of the resources folder or root of the classpath. This will override the Spring Boot logging template. Here used 'RollingFileAppender'. See an example [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/logback/logback-rollingfileappender-example/)

   ```
   <property name="DEV_HOME" value="c:/logs" />

   <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
       class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
       <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
       <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
           <Pattern>
               %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
           </Pattern>
       </encoder>

       <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
           <!-- rollover daily -->
           <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                       </fileNamePattern>
       </rollingPolicy>

   </appender>

   <logger name="com.example" level="debug"
       additivity="false">
       <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
   </logger>

   <root level="error">
       <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
   </root>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Slf4j is just the API. You need to choose an implementation for that.

With Spring Boot, I think the easiest choice is to use Logback (which is a slf4j implementation by Ceki). If Logback is available, then Spring Boot will use it.

If you put a logback.xml in the root of your classpath it will be picked up from there, and the logging will be configured according to that.

For starting a new log file daily you need something like this in logback.xml:

```
  <appender name="file"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log.path}/log.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601,Etc/UTC} %t %-5level %logger %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log.path}/log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<root level="ALL">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
```